# Tool to Find Out What The Browser is Downloading

Tags: browser

My PHP Apache website starts to load a part of the content, then it seems to stop loading and then it appends the rest of the page.

I would like to know if there is any tool to find out what exactly is being load at the moment by my browser.

I prefer Firefox, but any browser works.

Comment: Get Firbug http://getfirebug.com/. In the net tab you can see what is downloading by browser etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of @Ehtesham, I am using Firebug for this purpose.
I didn't know that it had this functionality.

To download firebug for Firefox: [Download Page](http://getfirebug.com/)